# "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because "dcs" is null

Tags: spring-boot, glassfish, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

After I call an OpenAPI function,  I get an exception, "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because dcs is null". The environment is Java 17/Spring boot 3.1.2, openapi-generator-maven-plugin(6.6.0 jersey2 library). How do I fix the glassfish issue and OpenAPI ?

**Logging:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because "dcs" is null
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.InjectionManagerFactory.create(InjectionManagerFactory.java:32)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.findInjectionManager(ClientConfig.java:482)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:834)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:181)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.onBuilder(JerseyWebTarget.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:38)
    at ca.bc.gov.jrcc.api.handler.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:998)
    at ca.bc.gov.jrcc.api.DefaultApi.jediXmlMessagePostWithHttpInfo(DefaultApi.java:150)
    at ca.bc.gov.jrcc.api.DefaultApi.jediXmlMessagePost(DefaultApi.java:101)
```

**POM file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ca.jrcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ords-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <default-package>ca.jrcc</default-package>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version> <!-- suppress error in eclipse https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846 -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
            <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configHelp>false</configHelp>
                    <configOptions>
                        <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spring-boot-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/jedi_ords.swagger.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                            </configOptions>
                            <library>jersey2</library>
                            <apiPackage>${default-package}.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${default-package}.api.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>${default-package}.api.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>nexus-release</id>
            <url>${env.NEXUS_URL}/repository/jrcc-releases</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>${env.NEXUS_URL}/repository/jrcc-snaps</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated pom.xml to move away generating OpenAPI source away from glassfish such as removing jersey2 and solved the issue.

```
<?xml versibon="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ca.jrcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ords-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <default-package>ca.jrcc</default-package>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version> <!-- suppress error in eclipse https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16846 -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
            <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spring-boot-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/jedi_ords.swagger.yml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <validateSpec>false</validateSpec>

                                <!-- javax.* to jakarta.* -->
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            </configOptions>

                            <apiPackage>${default-package}.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${default-package}.api.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>${default-package}.api.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```